# Replace character at a given position without affecting another similar character within the filename

Tags: php

I have this kind pdf filename,

> 20160.pdf

and I would like to replace `0` at position `4` count start to `0`, I tried using something like this,

```
$filename[0] = "20160";
$filename[1] = "pdf";
$adds        = 1;
$new_filename = str_replace($filename[0][4], $adds, $filename[0]) . '.' . $filename[1];
```

where `4` in `$filename[0][4]` generated by getting the string length of `filename[0]`.

Question is how to replace character at position 4 only without affecting another similar character within the filename?

Comment: What is your expected output ?

Comment: You can directly $filename[0][4] = 'wahteveryouwant' <- check length before though

Comment: `str_replace` replaces all occurrences. If the character to replace is always at the same position @KA_lin's suggestion may be enough for you. Otherwise you might want to use `preg_replace`

Comment: Take a look at `substr_replace()`

Comment: @Aniruddha, the expected output should be 20161.pdf

Comment: @Fil , i added an answer for this question , hope it will work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go!

```
$filename[0] = "20160";
$filename[1] = "pdf";
$adds        = 1;

$filename[0][strlen($filename[0]) - 1] = $adds;

echo $newfilename = $filename[0].'.'.$filename[1];
```

> And the output is "20161.pdf"

Comment: Nice, we have similar idea, but, i think there is another better, useful for dynamic filename